# How to create a Login in userform with 2 or 3 Username and Password?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask how to create a login details in userform with 2 or 3 Usernames and Password?

Please see attached pictures[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTmAD.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ3sD.png).

This is my code I was trying:

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  If Me.tb1.Value = "Admin2019" Then
     If Me.tb2.Value = "askyourmanager" Then
        LoginFlag = True
        MsgBox "Mr. Jim would like to welcome you"
        ElseIf Me.tb1.Value = "admin" Then
           If Me.tb2.Value = "pw" Then
           LoginFlag = True
           MsgBox "Welcome Mr. Jim"
           Unload Me
           Exit Sub
           End If
         End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  MsgBox "Sorry, Incorrect Login Details"
  End Sub
```

I get this error:

> > End If without block If

Comment: Please don't post images. Actually copy the text. I've edited your question and added it. There are less `if` than `end if` in your code. You have four `if` and five `end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "Select Case" would be much easier to read. Here is an example.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim strUser As String
      Dim strPW As String
      Dim strWelcome As String

      strUser = Me.tb1.Value
      strPW = Me.tb2.Value

      Select Case True
         Case strUser = "Admin2019" And strPW = "askyourmanager"
            LoginFlag = True
            strWelcome = "Mr. Jim would like to welcome you"

         Case strUser = "admin" And strPW = "pw"
            LoginFlag = True
            strWelcome "Welcome Mr. Jim"

         Case Else
            LoginFlag = False
            strWelcome = "Sorry, Incorrect Login Details"

        End Select

        MsgBox strWelcome

        Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Solved!. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not indented properly...you first need to indent every if statement correctly.

You have one extra "End If" so try to remove one of those at the bottom and see if that's a quick fix. If not then you need to go through each "if" and make sure that there's a corresponding "End if" for it.

Basically the error is saying that there's one extra "End If" that does not have a starting "If".

Thanks